# Snipe command for images

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a working snipe command which sends an embed of the last deleted message, but it doesn't work for images. How do I fix it?

```
@bot.command(aliases=["sn"])
async def snipe(ctx):
    try:
        contents, author, channel_name, time = bot.sniped_messages[ctx.guild.id]
        
    except:
        await ctx.channel.send("**Couldn't find a message to snipe.**")
        return

    embed = discord.Embed(description=contents, color=0xffd1dc, timestamp=time)
    embed.set_author(name=f"{author.name}#{author.discriminator}", icon_url=author.avatar_url)
    embed.set_footer(text=f"Deleted in : #{channel_name}")
    await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Can you share the errors you're getting or what exacly isn't working? your code seems functional. I advice you remove the `except` line as it will block error traceback, then try again and paste the error if you like

Comment: It works with text, but it doesn't work with images. I removed the ```except``` line and now it gives me invalid syntax for the first line of the embed.

Comment: Im sorry i meant the entire except block, my bad. including the try. Just leave `contents, author, channel_name, time = bot.sniped_messages[ctx.guild.id]` at the same indentation level as the rest of the code

Comment: Still works only with text

Comment: also no errors in the logs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I allowed images to be sniped:

```
client.sniped_messages = {}
@client.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
    if message.attachments:
        bob = message.attachments[0]
        client.sniped_messages[message.guild.id] = (bob.proxy_url, message.content, message.author, message.channel.name, message.created_at)
    else:
        client.sniped_messages[message.guild.id] = (message.content,message.author, message.channel.name, message.created_at)

@client.command()
async def snipe(ctx):
    try:
        bob_proxy_url, contents,author, channel_name, time = client.sniped_messages[ctx.guild.id]
    except:
        contents,author, channel_name, time = client.sniped_messages[ctx.guild.id]
    try:
        embed = discord.Embed(description=contents , color=discord.Color.purple(), timestamp=time)
        embed.set_image(url=bob_proxy_url)
        embed.set_author(name=f"{author.name}#{author.discriminator}", icon_url=author.avatar_url)
        embed.set_footer(text=f"Deleted in : #{channel_name}")
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
    except:
        embed = discord.Embed(description=contents , color=discord.Color.purple(), timestamp=time)
        embed.set_author(name=f"{author.name}#{author.discriminator}", icon_url=author.avatar_url)
        embed.set_footer(text=f"Deleted in : #{channel_name}")
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
```